# Define Travic CI test code coverage with coveralls (scala)

Tags: scala, code-coverage, travis-ci, coveralls, scoverage

I successfully configured and used Travis CI with combination of Coveralls.io as you can see in [the project](https://github.com/yetu/siren-scala). Since this is a open-source project I'd love to define 90% test code coverage threshold. Does anyone know how to define such a threshold in Travis CI with combination of coveralls.io?

Thank you!

Best

Comment: What code coverage tool are you using

Comment: Scoverage (before known as coveralls) [https://github.com/scoverage]

Comment: scoverage and coveralls are different. scoverage is the code coverage tool, and coveralls is a site that just tracks it over time. You have both in your project which is good. You need to upgrade your scoverage version as its out of date, bump to 0.99.7.1 and then add these lines to your build.sbt "ScoverageKeys.minimumCoverage := 80

ScoverageKeys.failOnMinimumCoverage := true"